# Placeholders not replaced inside a docx template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, docx, neutralinojs, easy-template-x

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/alonrbar/easy-template-x) to replace some placeholders into a docx template and generate multimple documents. I'm using neutralino and vue for the front-end and I've created a method that will pass the selected docx file and the data to the library for processing. I've used a for loop in this way

```js
// putting all the desired data into a specific array
for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedData.length; i++){
  this.dataPlaceholders.push({
   key1: val1,
   key2: val2
  })
}
//call the library to get documents

for(let i; i < this.dataPlaceholders.length; i++){
 this.docxTemplate.process(template, this.dataPlaceholders[i])
}
```

the data to pass are merged from two array and if I console log them I'm able to see that all si in place. As explained into the docs, I'm using the brackets `{}` to set the placeholders and the name of the placeholders is the same that I have for each key in the `dataPlaceholders` array. After A test I've noticed that I'm able to generate different documents, but the placeholders will be not replaced and I will have blank fields into the documents.

How I can fix it to make this owrk correctly?

Comment: What is the object represented by `this.docxTemplate`? I would assume it's a `new TemplateHandler()` based on a quick reading of the docs for the Easy Template X library. If so, I don't believe the code snippet you have above is actually `await`ing or saving the result of the `process()` call. Since you mentioned that you are successfully generating different documents, could you provide a little bit more code to show how you're receiving the files and viewing the un-replaced template strings?

Comment: @RNanoware the `docxTemplate` is an instance of the library. At the moment, I'm using a `then()` block to get the result of the processed document and creating a download link using an anchor tag with a blob url. Probably I need to use an async function?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without seeing a little more code. If you're using Promises and `then` properly, I wouldn't expect async/await to produce any better results (since it's just syntactic sugar for the same code). I'd recommend adding your Promise-handling code to your snippet, to help folks narrow down the possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries and after reading some questions on how to implement an async call inside a loop, I've opted to use the `Array.prototype.map` function and it's working fine. I've modified my vue method that is calling the library to an async method, but I leave untuched the `then` block so I will be able to get the processed documents after the library finished processing them.

```js
this.dataPlaceholders.map( async (data, i) => {
  let filename = data.supplier + '.docx'
  this.docxTemplate.process(template, data).then( (result) => {
    // code to download files here
     let a = document.createElement('a')
     let downloadLink = URL.createObjectURL(result)
     a.href = downloadLink
     a.download = filename
     a.click()
  })
})
```

The only thing to solve is how I can revoke the blob url after all files are downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a for loop instead of the `map` function, if your function is async you can try using this code

```js
async function myFunc(){
    for( let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ){
        await functionTocall(param1, param2)
    }
}
```

The for loop will wait until the async function return a promise, in this way you will be sure that the function inside the loop will be executed correctly.